# I am creating objecting in the classes of a instance at "Syncano' . I am reveiving this ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Tags: node.js, syncano

Here's the error log
ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at Object. (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\JsGame-master\APP.JS:137:45)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3

```
var connection = Syncano({apiKey: 'abc',
                              userKey: 'abc', 
                              defaults: { 
                                          instanceName: "interactiveboard", 
                                          className: "players"
                                        }
                             });

    var DataObject = connection.DataObject;

    DataObject  .please() .list()  .then(function(res) { 
          console.log(res);
      });

    var dataObject = {
      avatar: "Geralt", 
      nickname: "Rivia",
      email:"whatevershit@gmail.com"
    };

    DataObject.please().create(DataObject).then(callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `callback` you are passing into `DataObject.please().create(DataObject).then(callback);` is not defined anywhere.

You could solve this in two ways.

One would be to define a callback before you pass it into that call like this:

```
var callback = function(res) { console.log(res); };
```

The other would be to change your last line to pass the function directly into the `then` call like this:

```
DataObject.please().create(DataObject).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Hope this helps!